# Deploy Azure Analysis Services and Azure DB Connection using YAML Pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-analysis-services

I am creating Yaml Pipeline to deploy AAS.
Now I want to know how to add database credentials for AAS while deploying. the Source is Azure sql db and it doesn't have username/pw. It is configured using AAD.
I would like to know various options of configuring this as source for AAS in Powershell script.  I would like to avoid using username and p/w if possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, AAD credentials are not supported in AAS. You have to connect using a username and password.

Comment: Thanks @NiharikaMoola, How can I deploy AAS with connection to sql to use AAD? If I can do it through Visual Studio why I cannot do it through PowerShell?